# Grouping not working with OLAP Cube

Tags: excel, ssas, data-warehouse, olap

Having difficulty with some data that is view able through SSAS from a cube. When attempting to group say Engine Size values thatare INTEGER's, previously Excel was able to group and would ask me how I would like to 'Band' the values.

Using the Cube (SSAS) data this is not possible, what is occurring is the value I right click and 'Group' goes into 'Group 1' and everything else is 'Other'.

Can anyone shed some light?

Comment: How did you want them grouped? I would make sure I had fields in the Dimension table that would do the grouping for me in a Pivot table.

Comment: I believe that the ad-hoc grouping feature you mention is only available when you pivot data in an excel sheet. Like @manderson mentioned add any fields and groupings of that field to a dimension in the cube.

Comment: @GregGalloway - That's exactly what I have done but obviously the 'grouping' is fixed then as in I set the from and to figures where as doing it in Excel is dynamic and the user can choose whatever they wish to band by.